# cakephp3- table sorting not working

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

Version: 3.3.*

I’m using the $paginator->sort() method to create links in the column headers for tables of paginated search results in my CMS. You should be able to click them once to sort in ascending order, and then click again to reverse into descending order. But the reverse was never working for me.

But this is not for all fields. Let say I have 5 fields.

```
<tr class="design">
    <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Students.id','Id',array('class'=>'link')); ?></th>
    <th scope="col"><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Students.userName','Name',array('class'=>'link')); ?></th>
    <th scope="col"><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Students.age','Age',array('class'=>'link')); ?></th>
    <th scope="col"><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Students.currentClass','Class',array('class'=>'link')); ?></th>
    <th scope="col"><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Students.dateJoined','Joined Date',array('class'=>'link')); ?></th>
</tr>
```

I can sort the table both ways using `username`, `age`, and `school` but not using `id` and `joined`. When I fetch the list initially I have specified in my Model function to fetch result based on `id` and `joined` in ascending order.
Is it because of this, I'm not being able to sort it in descending order?

Is there any way I can achieve this?

**Controller function**

```
public function index()
{
    //Listing Students
    $this->paginate = [
                        'finder'        =>  'ListStudents',
                        'sortWhitelist' => ['Students.id',
                                            'Students.userName',
                                            'Students.age',
                                            'Students.currentClass',
                                            'Students.dateJoined',],
                        'limit'         => 25,
                        ];
    $students = $this->paginate($this->Students);  
    $this->set(compact('students'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['students']);
}
```

**Model Function**

```
public function findListStudents(Query $query, array $options)
{   
    $query 
            ->select(['id','userName','age','currentClass','dateJoined'
                ])
    $query->group('Students.id');

    $query->order(['status' => 'asc']);
    $query->order(['Students.dateJoined' => 'asc']);
    $query->order(['Students.id' => 'asc']);  
    return $query;
}
```

The issue mentioned in this [link](http://blog.room34.com/archives/3481) is similar to the one I'm facing.I tried the solution mentioned in it but it ain't working.

Comment: You ask whether specifying the sort order in your custom finder might be the problem. Seems that would be a very trivial thing for you to test on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you have to modify your controller and model functions a little bit.

First of all, add extraOptions to your controller function

```
public function index()
{
    //Listing Students
    $this->paginate = [
                        'finder'        =>  'ListStudents',
                        'sortWhitelist' => ['Students.id',
                                            'Students.userName',
                                            'Students.age',
                                            'Students.currentClass',
                                            'Students.dateJoined',],
                        'limit'         => 25,
                         'extraOptions' =>[
                    'params' => $params                                       ]
                        ];
    $students = $this->paginate($this->Students);  
    $this->set(compact('students'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['students']);
}
```

Now you need to override your `dateJoined` and `id` sort order. By default, its `asc`.
If user passes a specific direction, it should be taken. So, for that you need to modify your model function a little.

```
public function findListStudents(Query $query, array $options)
{   
    $query 
            ->select(['id','userName','age','currentClass','dateJoined'
                ])
    $query->group('Students.id');
    $direction  = (!empty($options['extraOptions']['params']['direction'])) ? $options['extraOptions']['params']['direction'] : 'asc';
    $query->order(['status' => 'asc']);
    $query->order(['Students.dateJoined' => $direction]);
    $query->order(['Students.id' => $direction]); 
    return $query;
}
```

Now sorting will work fine when you are passing a specific direction.

Comment: `$params` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

> When I fetch the list initially I have specified in my Model function
>   to fetch result based on id and joined in ascending order. Is it
>   because of this, I'm not being able to sort it in descending order?

Yes, this is the case. You can verify that by commenting out the `$query->order` statements in your custom finder method. You will find out that descentant sorting `Students.id` will work then.

I would recommend to simply leave the sorting out of the custom finder method and define the default sorting options when configuring your `$paginate` variable instead.

**StudentsController**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'finder' =>  'ListStudents',
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'Students.id',
            'Students.userName',
            'Students.age',
            'Students.currentClass',
            'Students.dateJoined'
        ],
        'limit' => 25,

        // add custom sorting options here
        'order' => [
            'Students.status' => 'asc',
            'Students.dateJoined' => 'asc',
            'Students.id' => 'asc' 
        ]
    ];
    $students = $this->paginate($this->Students);  
    $this->set(compact('students'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['students']);
}
```

**StudentsTable**

```
public function findListStudents(Query $query, array $options)
{   
    $query ->select([
        'id', 'userName', 'age', 'currentClass', 'dateJoined'
    ]);
    $query->group('Students.id');

    // remove the sorting here
    /*
    $query->order(['status' => 'asc']);
    $query->order(['Students.dateJoined' => 'asc']);
    $query->order(['Students.id' => 'asc']);  
    */

    return $query;
}
```